# Error en sentencias sql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un error en las siguientes sentencias de SQL, trabajo en mysql y el comando es para actualizar los datos de un usuario en el servidor, he hecho varias pruebas y he descubierto que el error esta en la sentencia ya que reduciendo código descubrí que la página se cuelga cuando intenta hacer el update.

Este es el código:

```
    <?php
    include 'include_sesions.php';
    
    if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) { // <= false
        $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user="$_POST[first_name]" where Correo_user='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql);
        // No está vacía (true)
    }
    if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) { // <= false
        $sql1 = "UPDATE usuario SET Apellido_user="$_POST[last_name]" where Correo_user='$email'";
        $conexion->query($sql1);
        // No está vacía (true)
    }
    if (isset($_POST['provincia'])) { // <= false
        $sql2 = "UPDATE usuario SET Provicncia_user="$_POST[provincia]" where Correo_user='$email'";
        $conexion->query($sql2);
        // No está vacía (true)
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cp'])) { // <= false
        $sql3 = "UPDATE usuario SET CP_user="$_POST[cp]" where Correo_user='$email'";
        $conexion->query($sql3);
        // No está vacía (true)
    }

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La variable $email esta declarada dentro del include_sesion.php

Comment: Y que error te da?

Comment: Esta pagina no funciona, error http 500

Comment: Es un error de servidor revisa el log de errores ahí se grabó el fallo, encuéntralo y agrégalo a tu pregunta

Comment: he puesto una imagen en la pregunta

Comment: Voto cierre por pregunta duplicada (y respondida): [Error de escritura en sentencia UPDATE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386157/error-de-escritura-en-sentencia-update)

Answer (score 5):

Me parece que tu error es el siguiente:

Tu usas `$_POST[last_name]` y debería ser como sigue `$_POST['last_name']`, te estaban faltando las comillas.

Otro tema, te falta concatenar con el `.` tu tienes esto:

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user="$_POST['first_name']" where Correo_user='$email'";
```

y debería ser algo como esto:

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET Nombre_user= "."'".$_POST['first_name']. "."'". " where Correo_user='" .  $email .  "'";
```

Saludos!

Comment: Todavía falta encerrar los valores entre comillas para que no falle la consulta.

Comment: Que valores?, he probado lo que dices pero sigue dando error.